# Replayer breaks when the first fullmove number is 10 or more

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

First fullmove number is 2:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2"]

2. Nf3
```

First fullmove number is 10:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 10"]

10. Nf3
```

AFAICT, both of these *should* show the replayer, but only the former *does*.

Comment: That the replayer does not accept beyond 1 is a generally known fact.